# Get Wtime function returning "***"

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran77, intel-fortran

I'm currently working on converting some Fortran code into parallel using openMP. I'm trying to use `omp_get_wtime()` to calculate how much actual time passes, but its returning ******. Other OpenMP functions work, yet for some reason this doesn't. I've removed all the code from in between the timer just to try to get something different. Removing the finish, and just displaying the start gives the same result. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
C$    USE OMP_LIB
   DOUBLE PRECISION START,FINISH

   START = OMP_GET_WTIME()
   FINISH=OMP_GET_WTIME()

   WRITE(OUT,850) FINISH-START
 850 FORMAT(25X,'ELAPSED TIME',I6)
```

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `OMP_GET_WTIME` function. Rather it stems from the fact that the `I` edit descriptor is used to display integers and you are feeding it with a double precision number instead. You should use one of the floating-point edit descriptors like, e.g. `F10.6`:

```
$ cat wtime.f
      USE OMP_LIB
      IMPLICIT NONE
      DOUBLE PRECISION START,FINISH

      START = OMP_GET_WTIME()
      CALL SLEEP(1)
      FINISH=OMP_GET_WTIME()

      WRITE(*,850) FINISH-START
 850  FORMAT(25X,'ELAPSED TIME',F10.6)
      END
$ ifort -openmp -o wtime.exe wtime.f
$ ./wtime.exe
                         ELAPSED TIME  1.000277
```

Comment: I tried changing it to that, and it's still giving me the same out put:
 ELAPSED TIME **********

Comment: You have to uncomment the `USE OMP_LIB` operator or add `DOUBLE PRECISION OMP_GET_WTIME`, or otherwise the compiler will assume that `OMP_GET_WTIME` returns a real number and would not generate the proper call instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm compiling using ifort with the -openmp option, which tells it to read anything starting with c$. However, I tried just both of your suggestions, uncommenting and adding the double precision, both to no avail.

Comment: Try write(*,*) 'Elapsed Time ', finish-start.  It will tell you how big the number is.  Then you can modify the format statement to make it look pretty